# Editing a document in Adobe Acrobat XI – The font changes

Tags: fonts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am trying to edit an existing Adobe Acrobat document.

The document uses one font, but when I write text in, the text is written in mono or some nonsense.

The document tells me the font the existing text is in, but doesn't let me select the font for use - is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should have that font installed on your system if you want to make changes in an Adobe Acrobat PDF file. Otherwise it will use another default system font on whatever text you'll try to change.

If you open the "Content Editing" tools, you should have access to other fonts at least and change it. Your only other option is to have the exact same font version as the one in the PDF installed on your system!

It's possible the font you have has the same name as the one in Acrobat but there's many versions of fonts and Acrobat might not recognize yours as being the same. That doesn't stop you from changing some parts manually to your font if it works.

You should be able to select a new font.

[image: Acrobat text Editing Tools]

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible the font is contained within the PDF itself, but in such a way that you can't add new text that uses it.

PDFs can carry fonts within themselves in two ways:

- *Embedding*, where a complete copy of the font is added to the PDF
- *Subsetting*, where only *part* of the font is contained in the PDF—specifically only the glyphs needed (e.g. if there was only the string 'Hello' in that font, then only the glyphs 'H', 'e', 'l' and 'o' would be subset in the PDF).

Subsetting is much more common, because it takes less space and also makes it harder to recover the font (font vendors really want you to buy a copy of the font for yourself).  However, it's almost impossible to add new text using a subset font (since you possibly don't have all the glyphs you'll need), and as such Acrobat Pro and other tools refuse to let you do it.

In the document properties, it should tell you if a font is embedded or subset.  go-meek is right, though: your only option in that case is to use a different font that you have available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Bharal, there many online pdf editors why don't you try them. I recommend **PDFescape** for [editing pdf files online](http://www.thesoftwarehax.com/2015/12/top-5-free-online-pdf-editor-viewer.html) because it has some great features like sharing option, form filling option and another great feature is you can protect your pdf by password.

Comment: And the problem with this online tool is that one looses the control over the own data.  In my eyes it is better to install one of the free pdf tools ...